# Use inline styling in react does not auto Reload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, inline-styles

I am new to React!
When I do inline style in React, no any changes, the page does not auto-reload, not working even if I reload the page manually. Its change the style only if I end the complied in the terminal and run again ==> `npm start`

What's the reason for that? What am I doing wrong?`

**Thank You! I found the solution, but I leave this post here, maybe someone has the same issue. My browser did not auto-reload when I do styling. My solution was : `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p` This fixed my problem. Thanks anyway!!!**

...

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const Header = (props) => {
  const { branding } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: '50px' }}>{branding}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

Header.defaultProps = {
  branding: 'My App'
};

Header.protoTypes = {
  branding: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default Header;
```

...

Package.json file :

...

```
{
  "name": "contactmanager",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

...

Comment: Edit your question and add your answer there.